# How to use APPLY format() with a loaded JSON value when aggregating in Redis?

Tags: database, indexing, redis, aggregate, full-text-search

I am trying to run an [`FT.AGGREGATE`](https://redis.io/commands/ft.aggregate/) command's [`APPLY format(...)`](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/advanced-concepts/aggregations/#list-of-string-apply-functions) sub-expression on Redis with RedisJson, but trying to use a JsonPath as a format parameter gives me an `Unknown symbol` error.

I have several JSON-type keys in the format of i.e. `{"shape": "circle", "color": "blue", "material": "metal"}`, and I want an index that will return each shape's color and material combinations, i.e. for circles, give `["blue metal", "red wood"]`.

I create a search index using `FT.SEARCH shapeSearch ON JSON SCHEMA $.shape as shape TAG SORTABLE`, which works fine. I then try to aggregate with `FT.AGGREGATE shapeSearch "@shape:{circle}" LOAD 2 $.color $.material APPLY "format(\"%s %s\", @$.color, @$.material)" AS colorAndMaterial GROUPBY 1 @shape REDUCE TOLIST 1 @colorAndMaterial`. The aggregation command fails, saying `Unknown symbol 'color'`.

I assume the issue is caused by the dot in `@$.color`, which Redis sees as a special character, and doesn't recognize the full JsonPath as a parameter. Trying to escape it like `@$\.color` doesn't work, putting it into a string like `\"@$.color\"` or `@\"$.color\"` simply puts the path into the formatted string, not the value.

How can this be done?

Comment: NOTE: I cannot make the loaded values part of the index. In this exmaple they're simple indexable values, but in my real-world use case they're large nested structures, which should only be accessed on query-time, not index-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to dig a bit for this one. Always like a good question like this. Helps make me smarter too!

So, for this to work, you need to provide and AS alias in the LOAD statement. This doesn't put it in the index but does give Search a name it can reference.

This is mentioned very briefly in the [documentation](https://redis.io/docs/interact/search-and-query/advanced-concepts/aggregations/#apply-expressions) and I almost missed it myself. Here's the salient bit is:

> APPLY steps must have an explicit alias determined by the AS parameter.

So, replace your call to FT.AGGREGATE with the following and you should be in like Flynn:

```bash
redis.cloud> FT.AGGREGATE shapeSearch "@shape:{circle}" LOAD 6 $.color AS color $.material AS material APPLY "format(\"%s %s\", @color, @material)" AS colorAndMaterial
1) (integer) 1
2) 1) "color"
   2) "blue"
   3) "material"
   4) "metal"
   5) "colorAndMaterial"
   6) "blue metal"
```

BTW, props for some solid usage of RediSearch. Nice to see it being well utilized!

And, of course, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you!! Quite straightforward, glad that this is possible.